# Spring FactoryBean - Object Based On Values In Other Object

Tags: java, spring

Getting right to it with a silly example:

Suppose I have created a FactoryBean implementation to create a Manager object.

```
public class ManagerFactory implements BeanFactory<Manager> {

    // implemented methods from interface

}
```

Now, this factory needs to take a field called employeeId in order to look up an employee to prepopulate various fields of the Manager bean that the ManagerFactory creates (Yes, I know, in the real world Manager would extend Employee, lets pretend I can't do that).

So, since this employeeId field is not constant, is the only way to deal with this to create a setEmployeeId() method in the FactoryBean, then get the FactoryBean itself, then set the employeeId before calling getObject()?

Or am I making no sense whatsoever?

Jason

Comment: Can you make your example a bit more realistic? Entity beans are typically created in the domain layer(by a factory, for example). You should not use Spring BeanFactory for this - BeanFactory is rather for people who create infrastructure frameworks and want to provide single configurable interface for integration with Spring Framework(and this interface usually creates another framework specific factory) as single bean(this bean is some kind of façade)

Comment: Also any bean can work as factory in Spring - that is possible with factory method construction(this factory bean should never implement BeanFactory of course)

Comment: Okay, I get what you are saying. I was trying to leverage the Spring infrastructure to create some complex POJOs for me.